# Specialty Panniers

Tags: commuter

I am checking out panniers.  I'd like to find something that would be waterproof, suitable to carry groceries in, but also to carry art supplies in on occasion.  An 11X14 pad of paper, a water bottle or two, and some paints.  How/where can I find this?

Comment: From what you're describing, it seems to me that most panniers in the marketplace would fit your requirements. I mean, many will be waterproof, and being able to fit something 14" long doesn't seem to be a particularly big ask. Are you just basically asking someone to recommend a decent pannier to you?

Comment: @PeteH 14" long without being enormous is not common.

Comment: two of the top three bestselling panniers on the Wiggle web site show dimensions in excess of 14". Uncommon?

Comment: @PeteH "without being enormous"  No there are not a lot of panniers that will carry an 11X14 pad of paper and not crush it. OP made it clear they did not want something much bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Ortlieb  Office has the dimensions you are looking for without being enormous.
[Ortlieb  Office](http://www.ortleib.com/_prod.php?lang=en&produkt=officebag_bnw&biketoy=cityoffice)

Comment: Why should the Op choose these panniers over other panniers on the market? Why do the panniers you're talking about better fit their requirements? As it stands this is hardly a complete answer.

Comment: @PeteH  Did you follow the link?  It has the dimensions the OP is looking for.